# Display to cout stops execution using g++

Tags: c++, cout

I am new to C++, I'm working on tokenizing input. The commented line "cout<< "p: " << p << endl;" makes the 2nd function call not execute, why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string.h> //for library strtok()
#include <sstream> //for useStringStream()
using namespace std;

void useStrTok(){
    char myString[] = "The quick brown fox";
    char *p = strtok(myString, " ");
    while (p) {
        cout<< "token: " << p<< endl;
        p = strtok(NULL, " ");
        //cout<< "p: " << p << endl;
    }
}    

void useStringStream(){
    string myText("The quick brown fox");
    istringstream iss(myText);
    string token;
    while(getline(iss,token, ' '))
    {
        cout << token << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    useStrTok();
    useStringStream();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: It's not a good idea to print a null character pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because  a null pointer maybe returned by strtok and print null pointer causes the crash. Check validation of pointer before accessing it:

```
if (p)
{
    cout<< "p: " << p << endl;
}
```

See [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) reference

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cout<< "p: " << (void*)p << endl;
```

Simplest thing to fix your issue, but might not do what you intend.